# Syncing action and lips of a charecter with pre recorded voice over

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I am trying to animate my character according to the pre recorded voice over, but the problem is my 3D view port is running at 3 FPS, and I want my animation at 24fps.
I wonder how complex scenes in movies are animated if it is too slow.
Anyway, is there any work around to complete my job?
I also want to to know what are the hardware specifications I should have to play my viewport playback at required FPS

Comment: Please share screenshot, where we can see your scene and modifier stack.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you can try. I would first enable [Simplify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/properties.html#simplify) to make the scene a little lighter while you're animating.

Another way to make your animations run faster is to split up the blend file into multiple files, and use them as [linked libraries](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html). You'd have one file with the rigged character model, another one with the scene, and a third one with the animation data. You can then link the rigged character into the animation file, make a [local proxy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#proxy-objects) of the armature, and animate the character. Because the animation file doesn't contain the rest of the scene, your computer will have an easier time moving from frame to frame. Once you have the animation the way you want it, you can link the animated character into the scene for lighting & rendering.